# Remove Cygwin package files without losing details about what's installed?

Tags: cygwin

Internet research indicates that one can remove the Cygwin package files to save space.  Within the Cygwin installation folder, I have a subfolder (say) `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f` reflecting the mirror site.  The file `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64/setup.ini` seems to contain all the information about installed packages.  The only other folders/files are in the following two folder trees:

```
http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/noarch/release/*
http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64/release/*
```

Can I remove everything in the `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f` folder tree except `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64/setup.ini` and still have the installer know what I have installed, what needs updating, and what needs downloading for a re-install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about installed package is stored in

```
/etc/setup/installed.db
```

the cache in `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f`
is only needed during installation or re-installation of any package.

See info in the `Cygwin User Guide`
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-localdir

> After installing Cygwin, the cache is no longer necessary, but you may
> want to retain the packages as backups, for installing Cygwin to
> another system, or in case you need to reinstall a package.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you be able to explicitly state in your answer that all of `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f` can be erased, and the installer will still know what needs updating and what needs re-downloading for a re-install?  That is, if I understood your answer correctly.

Comment: your assumption is correct. The cache is not needed for further update. You can just move away the directory and try.